# how handle textchange event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me how to handle **TextChange** event in asp.net. Earlier respose highly appreciated.

```
string str = this.txtLog.Text.ToString();
int startPos = str.LastIndexOf("UID:") + "UID:".Length + 1;
int length = str.IndexOf("Sector") - startPos;
string sub = str.Substring(startPos, length);
readerUID = sub;
```

Comment: please detail what do you want?

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.txtLog.TextChanged += txtLogTextChanged;  

protected void txtLogTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do whatever you want on text changed
}
```

Comment: My text change event not getting hit.